# How to create a simple python code runner with Brython

Tags: javascript, python, html, editor, brython

I'm creating simple code editor which can run python code in & show the output & error messages. Currently I'm able to run a python code but the problem is the output is showing in the developer tools' console. I want to get that output & error messages to DOM element or pass as a string to a JS script

```
<script type="text/python">
from browser import document, window 
import tb as traceback

def run(event): 
    
    try: 
        exec(document['code'].value) 
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc()) 

document['run'].bind('click',run)

</script>
```

This is my code. 'code' is the id of text box which use to enter the code. 'run' is the id of run button. I want to get the output to a another text box or get as a string to my js script instead of displaying in developer tools' console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [brython-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brython-runner). You can run Python code in a string and handle standard output and error with custom callback functions. It runs the code with a Brython instance in the web worker.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pythonpad/brython-runner/lib/brython-runner.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
const runner = new BrythonRunner({
    stdout: {
        write(content) {
            // Show output messages here.
            console.log('StdOut: ' + content);
        },
        flush() {},
    },
    stderr: {
        write(content) {
            // Show error messages here.
            console.error('StdErr: ' + content);
        },
        flush() {},
    },
    stdin: {
        async readline() {
            var userInput = prompt();
            console.log('Received StdIn: ' + userInput);
            return userInput;
        },
    }
});
runner.runCode('print("hello world")');
</script>
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this module. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer & creating such a useful module. Can I know that how to work with code which contains user input like `inp=input()`. I try this one the demo site of your module https://pythonpad.github.io/brython-runner/ but end up with a error.

Comment: I'm glad that you liked the module. I've just edited the demo page to support the `input()` function and added related content and examples in the readme. Please check out the [brython-runner webpage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brython-runner) again. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I want. Thanks again for creating such a useful module. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
<body onload="brython()">

<script type="text/python">

from browser import document, window 
import traceback

def run(event): 
    try: 
        exec(document['code'].value) 
    except Exception:
        error_message=traceback.format_exc()
        document['error_message_textarea'].value=error_message

document['run'].bind('click',run)
</script>

<input id='code' value='print(123+"OK")'></input>
<button id='run'>
    RUN
</button>
<br>
<textarea id='error_message_textarea' style='color:red;width: 300px; height: 300px;'></textarea>


</body>
```